# Scope Issue in java

Tags: java, scope

```
public class Calculator {

    private int total;
    private int value;

    public Calculator(int startingValue){
        int total = startingValue;
        value = 0;
    }

    public int add(int value){
        int total = total + value;
        return total;
    }

    /**
    * Adds the instance variable value to the total
    */
    public int add(){
        int total += value;
        return total;
    }

    public int multiple(int value){
        int total *= value;
        return total;
    }

    public void setValue(int value){
        value = value;
    }

    public int getValue(){
        return value;
    }

}
```

The assignment says "For this exercise, we are going to take a look at an alternate Calculator class, but this one is broken. There are several scope issues in the calculator class that are preventing it from running.

Your task is to fix the Calculator class so that it runs and prints out the correct results. The CalculatorTester is completed and should function correctly once you fix the Calculator class."

I thought i did it right but it keeps telling me its wrong and the code will not run, how do i fix this scope issue?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You should also read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Did you try to debug it yourself? I'm sure you'd find the answer right away.

Comment: In your constructor, you probably want to say `this.total = startingValue;` instead of `int total = startingValue;`. Or just remove the `int` in front of it.

Comment: Also, value = value should be this.value = value

Answer (score 1):

In the methods `total` is declared again so that the instance variable `total` is not overritten. You can just remove the `int` in the method bodies.

Comment: This caused another error. the first line on the add(int value) method. Says total i not initalized

Comment: Refer to the answer by Bhavya.

Answer (score 1):

- You can just remove `int` from `int total` as it is creating a local variable, and there is no need of this as there is already a private variable total `private int total;` declared.
- Since both the function parameter name and private variable name is same i.e. `value`, so you should use `this.value=value` instead of `value=value;`

  ```
  private int total;
  private int value;

  public Calculator(int startingValue){
      int total = startingValue;
      value = 0;
  }

  public int add(int value){
      total = total + value;
      return total;
  }

  /**
   * Adds the instance variable value to the total
   */
  public int add(){
      total += value;
      return total;
  }

  public int multiple(int value){
      total *= value;
      return total;
  }

  public void setValue(int value){
      this.value = value;
  }

  public int getValue(){
      return value;
  }
  ```